# Re-installing Matplotlib problem (access denied) even with administrator privilage

Tags: python, matplotlib

My matplotlib version was 3.3.4 and I tried to customize my plot colormap with (matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)) it said maplotlib does not have colors.ListedColormap.

Then, I tried to upgrade the matplotlib version, uninstall it and reinstall it. However, I kept receiving access is denied even though I tried the following lines through Anaconda Prompt and Windows Command Line Prompt:
What should I do to install Matplotlib again? I wish did not want that colors.ListedColormap that caused me to lose all the matplotlib.

Through Anaconda Prompt (with and without admin access): (Each time I get the following Error)

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\io00002\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\_image.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'
Check the permissions.
```

- pip install matplotlib --force-reinstall --user
- pip install --user -U matplotlib
- conda install matplotlib
- python -m pip install -U matplotlib

Through Windows Command Prompt:

```
(Error: Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.)
Even though I tried to add Python path to the Environment Paths (not sure if I did it correctly through)
```

- python -m pip install -U matplotlib

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier. All packages are installed as precompiled binaries. [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/). **If you are using Anaconda, do not use `pip` to install packages that exist within the `conda` ecosystem.** Use `conda install package`. Only use `pip` if the package is not available with `conda install`. Using `pip` can potentially wreck your installation because `pip` and `conda` do not manage dependencies in the same way.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney sing Anaconda. I tried conda install matplotlib, it didnt work although it said all packages are installed but when I import matplotlib in Spyder it takes forever and give a lot of Import Error, AttributeError  TypeError, including "ImportError: cannot import name 'animation' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\io00002\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py) ":  "AttributeError: attr __class__ is a protected member of class Struct." I uninstalled it (un)install again did not work

Comment: You should just uninstall and reinstall anaconda